Locate specific node in shader/geo nodes/compositor
I'd like to know if there is a way to find specific nodes that have already been used in any of the graph editors.
For instance, let's say I'm aware I used Hue/sat/val node in my compositor/shader graph, but I don't know exactly where I put it because of how complex the graph has gotten.
Is there a way to quickly search for the node and blender snaps to its current location?
Thanks

After trying different things, turns out it was simply ctrl + F, like any other program
Blender doesn't snap to the node, it just selects it for you. Which also works for me.

You can hit Numpad . to center on a selected node.
